# How to make a number list in a Table

Tags: php, html

I have a leaderboard on my website, and I want to be able to have rank numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc) as using...

```
<ol>
<li>this</li>
<li>that</li>
</ol>
```

...doesn't work in a table

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question: where does the `table` come into this? Can you show the 'before' and what you want the mark-up to look like 'after' manipulation?

Comment: Don't put it in a table? If it's not tabular data, then it shouldn't be in there, if it is tabular data (it certainly sounds like it is), then create a separate column for "rank" and drop the OL.

Comment: was this question resolved to your needs? Or do you require additional help/advice? If it's been resolved, please consider marking one of the answers (the one that helped you the most usefully) as 'accepted' (click on the `✓` beside the answer and below the vote-count).

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving this, given the following structure:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank:</th>
            <th>Name:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="rank"><span></span></td>
            <td>Him</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rank"><span></span></td>
            <td>Her</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is to use CSS-counters:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    empty-cells: show;
    width: 40%;
    counter-reset: ranking;
}

th {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
    min-width: 4em;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 6em;
}
tbody tr {
    counter-increment: ranking;
}
td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
td.rank > span:before {
    content: counter(ranking);
}
```

And a [JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tYPgy/).

As noted elsewhere, though, these are not widely supported. And would be better-implemented either using JS/jQuery *or* by simply using an `ol`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using CSS counters

...unfortunately they're not that widely supported yet. It's best to generate the numbers on the server side, it could be argued that they are significant content and should be in HTML anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this to your CSS:

```
ol {
list-style-type: decimal;
margin-left:12px;
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/zhCzQ/2/

Or you could also use `list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid numbering rows in a table is a standard html feature. You'll need to resort to Javascript or server-side generation of the numbers.

*Edit:*

You really should do this via (in order of preference):

1. CSS numbering (see other answers)
2. Server-side (I don't do php - sorry)
3. client-side javascript should be a last resort:

   ```
       <table id="numbered">
         <tr>
           <td>a</td>
           <td>b</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>c</td>
           <td>d</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>e</td>
           <td>f</td>
         </tr>
       </table>

       <script type="text/javascript">
       var table=document.getElementById('numbered');
       var tr=table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
       for(var i=0; i<tr.length; i++)
       {
           var td=tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
           td[0].insertBefore(document.createTextNode(i+1+'. '), td[0].firstChild);
       }
       </script>
   ```

Comment: Server-side being the preferred method.

Comment: How would I do this with javascript or from the server side?

Answer (score -2):

As for me I am using while loop in a while loop (for php) If you wanted to get data from database.
Ex.

```
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table);
        $getnumbers = mysql_num_rows($query);

    $x=1; //initialize your number
  while($x<=$getnumbers)
    {
          while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
          {

            echo $x;echo $row["row1"];echo "<br>";
          $x++ }
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to put $x++ (after echo "<br>")